# PHP Storing high frequency user-updated content in text/dat-files or in a database

Tags: php, database, text

Background: I'm designing a new website, where pages is stored using the following procedure:

```
if (a cached version of page doesn't exist) {
    generate the page content from the database
    store the page content in the cache (IsPageCached=true)
}
serve the page from the cache
```

When editing a page:

```
store the new content in the database
wipe the cache for that page (IsPageCached=false)
```

In addition visitors can do *actions* on the pages. It is basically *likes* and a bunch of alternatives. Mostly counters.

Here's the questions:

1. What is the best practise to store the *IsPageCached* flag? I am thinking that the purpose of the cache is to limit database queries, so storing it in the database sounds counter productive. Should I just check if the file exists? doesn't that open up the possibility for read errors if the visitor happens to visit the page exactly when the page is updated and the cache is currently being wiped?
2. What is the best practise, performance wise, to handle visitor *actions*? Even if it is just counters, from anonymous visitors, should database queries be involved? The overhead sounds ridiculously high for such a basic feature, but I need the integrity on the data. Many visitors should be able to click on the different actions "at the same time" and the backend needs to be able to handle the flood of concurrent clicks.

Comment: Have a look at something like [varnish](https://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-with-varnish/)

Comment: As I understand it varnish is a separate server, or application, and act as a cached front to ease the load on the webserver/database. That sounds like a promising solution for my question #1, but not #2, if it weren't for the fact that the server park I am using is a web hotel and unluckily I don't have such control of it that I can install separate software. Perhaps I should have mentioned that in the question ..